# PHP concatenation issues

Tags: php, html

So I am really bad at concatenation Ive been working on it for an hour the best i can get this to do is no errors butit doesnt echo the username for some reason I am pretty sure it has to do with concatenation anyway.

Code:

```
echo '<span style="color: #"' . $row['color'] . ';"';
echo $row['user'] . ': ' . '</span>' . $row['message'] . '';    
echo '</br>';
```

Basically I am trying to make the username show the color of the the hex in database. But when I do this it doesnt even show the username just the message.

Comment: Try closing the first part of your <span> tag.. echo '<span style="color: #"' . $row['color'] . ';">';

Comment: `echo '<span style="color: #' . $row['color'] . ';">';`

Comment: Hmm that fixed the error not showing the username but for some reason its not showing the color.

Comment: Thank you logan wayne it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<span style="color: #' . $row['color'] . ';">'
. $row['user'] . ': </span>' . $row['message']
. '</br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the `<span>` tag.

You can also just output the entire string and interpolate the values:

```
echo "<span style=\"color:#{$row['color']}\">{$row['user']}:</span> {$row['message']}<br>";
```